# How to use jQuery Select on a <code> element or <blockquote> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select all the text with a `<code>` or  HTML element. I have tried a lot of things but I think that jQuery .select() only works for input boxes.

```
jQuery('code').click(function () {
  jQuery(this).select(); // text should now be highlighted in the browser
});
```

My HTML

```
<code>.alpha{}</code>
<code>Some other code element on the page.</code>
<blockquote>A famous quote</blockquote>
```

It should select and highlight the text

[image]

Comment: What do mean by _highlighted_? "selected"?

Comment: Here's [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/4049/) of the code from an answer in  the linked question.

Comment: @Tushar thanks for taking the time to do that demo +1

Comment: Can you please make an answer @Tushar so I can reward you.

Comment: No. The question is closed so no more answers can be added. Also, it is already asked. I've just created demo from the answer on linked question. You can upvote that answer.